# Issue with InstalShield

Tags: installshield

I Use Installsheild 2009 To Deployment VS2005 Project with Sql express 2005 DB.

I put my exe and DB files.

And I typed `/qn SQLAUTOSTART=1 ADDLOCAL=ALL DISABLENETWORKPROTOCOLS=1` in command line to Make Silent Install.

My problem is that after I build this project and I try using it, it only works if the computer has the requirements just by one click.

But if computer needs these requirements after installation, the user must click again on the setup icon to finish the setup.
So first click to install requirements  and second click to install my project

I need the progress does not stop until all the installation is done (the needed requirements and my project)

Answer (score 0):

I inherited a IS setup that installs SQL Express (previously 2005, now 2008). It handles this by adding itself to:
`HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`, before rebooting.